# How Can I Incorporate Solfege Into My Ear Training Routine?

Tags: ear-training

I read an article article about solfege, so I thought I would just sing do re mi in a major scale (probably C) and then move on to another scale when I have C scale down cold.

Is there a better way?

Also, what about for intervals? Do I just sing random intervals with the solfege?

Also I transpose and use ear training apps.

This is one last question, but is it a bad idea to learn notes first before moving onto scales?

Comment: Welcome! Singing a scale is the best place to start, yes, but there’s plenty more to do after that. A single answer here would be difficult to lay it all out; I suggest you Google something like “solfege sight singing training“, spend about 10 minutes looking through the results, and then you’ll probably have more focused questions that will be easier to address here.

Comment: Unless you already have absolute pitch, the question is vague. 'When I have C scale down cold' - do you think D scale will sound that different, if you haven't absolute pitch. It'll still be  do - re - mi - that's what movable do is all about. The question needs some clarity.

Comment: @Andy Bonner Sorry, I'll be more specific, are there any books you would recommend for beginning sight singing? I have Concone and A New Approach? But is most of my practice just singing scales and melodies from those scales?

Comment: @Tim I mean more like I can sing melodies that use the scale really well. But most exercises seem to be really easy melodies.

Comment: @t_t Don't underestimate "easy melodies". They can be extremely helpful in improving your tuning capabilities and, therefore, sight reading/singing ones. Take an "easy melody" and a completely random note as reference (for instance, by pushing a key on a keyboard without looking at it), then try to sing it. Then immediately do the same again with another random note. You'll probably find out some difficulties, depending on the pitch of the note and the context of previous examples. The Dunning-Kruger effect is always behind the corner.

Comment: @musicamante Do I always need a reference note? Or are you able to do it by hearing the noted in your head? Also, I read in another book to use hhe instrument as sparingly as possible. I guess it's obvious, but I should only use the piano as a reference right?

Comment: @t_t An external reference is better, because it *forces* you to use an external input rather than what you may implicitly "choose" (even if you *believe* it's random), which can be extremely important to develop further capabilities. You should not just use the instrument "as sparingly as possible", you should use it in *smart* ways. Consider it as an "instrument" in the broader sense. Piano is normally preferred because of various reasons: in this case, it's also simpler because you don't need to "think" too much about how to play the instrument, just push one key.